# How to make an alias for openvpn passing sudo password?

Tags: openvpn, .bash-profile

I'm trying to create an alias in my `.bash_profile`, as you can tell I'm new in Linux. This actually runs, but it gets frozen without asking me for my password.

```
alias convpn = 'cd ~/folder; echo <password> | sudo -S openvpn --config server@edu.com .ovpn'
```

Thanks.

Comment: `sudo` does not read from `stdin` when it's redirected. You need to use something like `expect`, and instead of an alias you will probably need to use a script or function, because of the complexity.

Comment: Thanks I think I will write a script using expect, and call it with an alias in the bash profile.

Comment: You might also want to enable passwordless sudo for that command.